# Phonegap image file is not saved permanently iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

Hi i'm trying to capture a photo and save it permanently to the filesystem. Taking the photo works so far, but it seems it doesn't save it permanently to the filesystem. After i restart the app, the pictures are gone.
The path of the picture is saved to my WebSQL Database (which works without problems)

Here is the part of my code:

```
function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI, saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
}

function onFail(message) {
    console.log('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageURI) {
    movePic(imageURI);
}

function movePic(file){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file, resolveOnSuccess, resOnError);
}

//Callback function when the file system uri has been resolved
function resolveOnSuccess(entry){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    //new file name
    var newFileName = n + ".jpg";
    var myFolderApp = "LeadAppPhotos";

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
            //The folder is created if doesn't exist
            fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp,
                {create:true, exclusive: false},
                function(directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                },
                resOnError);
        },
        resOnError);
}

//Callback function when the file has been moved successfully
function successMove(entry) {

    //put the path url in a div so i can save it later to my websql database
    $('#hidden_photo').val(entry.fullPath);
}

function resOnError(error) {
    alert(error.code);
}
```

What's my mistake?